# Using Cauchy's integral formula, what is $\int_\gamma \frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $p(z)$ be a polynomial with degree $n$ and $R > 0$ such that $|z_0| < R$ for all zeroes $z_0$. Using Cauchy's integral formula, show that

$$\int_{|z| = R} \frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}dz = 2 \pi i n$$

I am not asking for a full solution to this problem, but more or less for a hint.

Comment: Start by writing $p(z) = A(z-z_1)(z-z_2)\cdots(z-z_n)$ and compute $p'(z)/p(z)$.

Comment: @Winther Yeah, I also had that idea already. But it doesn't seems to help me.

Comment: Why not? What is the expression you get? Do you know how to compute integrals on the form $\oint \frac{dz}{z-\alpha}$ ?

Comment: @Winther I think it's $2 \pi i \cdot f(a) = 2 \pi i $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)} = \frac{d}{dz}\log p(z) = \frac{d}{dz}\left[\log A+\sum_{k=1}^n\log(z-z_k)\right] =\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{z-z_k}$$

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Since $p(z)$ has zeroes, how are you defining the multi-valued function $\log(p(z))$?

Comment: @MarkViola I am not sure either, but I guess we assume that $p(z)$ is nonzero, because otherwise the expression $\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}$ wouldn't be defined.

Comment: That is incorrect.  $p(z)$ is a polynomial of order $N$ and has, therefore, $N$ roots.  What on earth do you mean?  The OP explicitly states that all of the zeroes of $p(z)$ are on the interior of $|z|=R$.

Comment: @MarkViola I have to admit that I did not think about this when I wrote this answer. Thinking about it now, I am unsure, but would it not work to choose the branch cut along a straight line from the origin that does not contain any zeros? Then, away from this line, all the above should hold, and since we only have finitely many zeros, such a line will always exist.

Comment: @MarkViola Also, I guess one could avoid using the logarithm entirely and just do partial fraction decomposition of $\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}$ to get it into the rightmost form.

Comment: @MarkViola I mean the expression $\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}$ is not defined when $p$ admits any of its roots, and using an undefined expressions seems not valid to me. Maybe I also completely misunderstand your comment, because I am absolutely bad at Maths.

Comment: @ClassicEndingMusic The integration is taken over a path on which $p(z)\ne 0$.  So, the fact that $p(z)=0$ at its $n$ roots inside the integration contour is not a problem at all.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p(z)$ be a polynomial of order $N$ with $p(z)=\sum_{n=0}^N a_nR^ne^{in\phi}$, where $a_N\ne 0$.  Then, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{|z|=R}\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}\,dz&=\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} (n+1)a_{n+1}R^{n}e^{in\phi}}{\sum_{n=0}^N a_nR^ne^{in\phi}}\,iRe^{i\phi}\,d\phi\\\\
&=i\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\sum_{n=1}^{N} na_{n}R^{n}e^{in\phi}}{\sum_{n=0}^N a_nR^ne^{in\phi}}\,d\phi\tag1
\end{align}$$

Since all zeroes of $p(z)$ are contained in the circle $|z|=R$, Cauchy's Integral Theorem guarantees that we can take $R$ arbitrarily large.  Letting $R\to \infty$ in $(1)$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{|z|=R}\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}\,dz&=\lim_{R\to\infty}\oint_{|z|=R}\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}\,dz\\\\
&=i\int_0^{2\pi} \lim_{R\to\infty} \left(\frac{\sum_{n=1}^Nna_nR^{n-N}e^{in\phi}}{\sum_{n=0}^N a_nR^{n-N}e^{in\phi}}\right)\,d\phi\\\\
&=i\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{Na_Ne^{iN\phi}}{a_Ne^{iN\phi}}\,d\phi\\\\
&=2\pi iN
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: That's a very slick approach it looks like for $(1)$ , are there any other ways to address the problem besides the Residue Theorem and Cauchy's Integral Theorem ?

Comment: @Zophikel There might be a number of ways to tackle this, but the solution path seems particularly well suited to use of the residue theorem.

Comment: how would the Residue Theorem apply to  $\int_{|z| = R} \frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}dz$ where does  $f(z) = \frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}$ have poles ?

Comment: I don't understand your message.  The $N$ zeroes of $p(z)$ are poles of $\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}$